# How to add the "No-Auth-Challenge" request header to avoid the browser to prompt you for credentials with the awful popup login window in restAngular

Tags: angularjs, restangular, restheart

I am frequently getting **awful popup login window** in our website. I am using AngularJs with RestAngular for login.

I want to implement below solution:

As per the Rest-Heart documents.
[RestAngular Documentation](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/display/RH/An+example+Web+application+with+AngularJS+1.x)

Restangular is then configured to:

- **to add the No-Auth-Challenge request header to avoid the browser to prompt you for credentials with the awful popup login window.**

Can anyone help me to configure the same using **RestAngular**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using restangular you might want to give a try to angular-restheart package https://github.com/SoftInstigate/angular-restheart

It uses restangular and takes care of authentication and also set the no-auth-challenge header.

Looking at the code you'll find how to configure restangular with default headers

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders      ({
            'Accept': 'application/hal+json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'No-Auth-Challenge': 'true'
        });
```

Comment: Link was helpful.